# How to add a domain mask in Cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare, domain-forwarding

How to add a domain mask in Cloudflare? As far as I know Cloudfare didn't allow it before but I don't know the present status. I want to redirect a domain with a mask. Do they allow domain masks now?

Answer (score 2):

> Cloudflare does not offer domain masking services (your hosting
>   provider might). We only offer URL forwarding through Page Rules.

via [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168956-Does-Cloudflare-offer-domain-masking-)